Помогите с запятой
Люди, я учу запятые в русском языке (не из России), ставится ли запятая в таком случае: "или * или *"?

Этот вопрос похож на: Запятые перед ИЛИ?. Если вы уверены что это не так, нажмите [edit], дайте ясно понять, чем ваш вопрос отличается от дубликата и/или почему ответы на него не помогают решить вашу проблему.

Или-или      Разг. Экспрес. Всё или ничего.
Убивались или любили. Или — или.
Только нет в нём этого «или — или».
Если «или ‒ или», то я выбираю любовь.
